# Scala: Collect values defined in hashmap passed by a list argument

Tags: scala, list, hashmap

Suppose I have the following variables:

```
val m = HashMap( ("1", "one"), ("2", "two"), ("3", "three") )
val l = List("1", "2")
```

I would like to extract the list List("one","two"), which corresponds to the values for each key in the list present in the map.

This is my solution, works like a charm. Still I would like to know if I'm reinventing the wheel and if there's some idiomatic solution for doing what I intend to do:

```
class Mapper[T,V](val map: HashMap[T,V]) extends PartialFunction[T, V]{
    override def isDefinedAt(x: T): Boolean = map.contains(x)

    override def apply(x: T): V = map.get(x) match {
      case Some(v) => v
    }
}

val collected = l collect (new Mapper(map) )
```

> List("one", "two")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are reinventing the wheel. Your code is equivalent to

```
l collect m
```

but with additional layer of indirection that doesn't add anything to `HashMap` (which already [implements `PartialFunction`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap.html)—just expand the "Linear Supertypes" list to see that).

---

Alternatively, you can also use `flatMap` as follows:

```
l flatMap m.get
```

The implicit `CanBuildFrom`s make sure that the result is actually a `List`.

Comment: Oh, that's nice

Answer (score 2):

You could do this, which seems a bit simpler:

```
val res = l.map(m.get(_)) // List(Some("one"), Some("two"))
           .flatMap(_.toList)
```

Or even this, using a for-comprehension:

```
val res = for {
  key <- l
  value <- m.get(key)
} yield value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
m.collect { case (k, v) if l.contains(k) => v }
```

note:

- does not preserve the order from `l`
- does not handle the case of duplicates in `l`

Comment: This gives completely wrong result on any list with repeating elements, e.g. on `val l = List.fill(10)("1")`. Even on lists without repeating elements, it's not guaranteed to preserve the order.

Comment: You are right. It would be necessary to handle duplicates in l and it does not preserve the order defined in l. Also thanks for the really good answer.